# File Read in C++ Unexpected output

Tags: c++, iostream

This is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int grade; //declared globally because visual 2013 gives error if locally

int main() {

    ofstream outFile("C:\\Users\\Affan_000\\Desktop\\FileWrite.txt",ios::out);
    while (grade != -1){
        outFile << grade<<endl;
        cin >> grade;
    }
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

After entering the grades

> 80
>   50
>   60
>   40
>   90

when I opened the text file zero was at the top:

> 0
>   80
>   50
>   60
>   40
>   90

I have also tried it in Dev-C++.

Comment: You're printing `grade` before you perform the extraction.

Comment: Also, what is the error the compiler gives you when you declare `grade` locally?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I would guess at least a warning for reading from an uninitialized variable. The obvious solution would be to initialize it, not make it global.

Comment: Error 1 error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'grade' used

Comment: @user3150227 Well... because you are not initializing the local variable. That's bad -- how you expect it to contain anything meaningful without initialization?

Comment: @user3150227 Static variables are zero-initialized, which is why you don't get an error when you define it globally. Locally, this does not happen, and you are invoking Undefined Behavior for using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: OK  the you are right. You're printing grade before you perform the extraction. thanks bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from first writing and only then reading what should have been written, your code doesn't check if the input was successful: you should always check after reading that the read was successful

```
while (std::cin >> grade && grade != -1) {
    std::cout << grade << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not surprising, since inside the while loop, you are printing `grade` before putting the user input into it. Move the `cin >> grade;` statement **before** `outFile << grade << endl;` and it will be fine.

However, now you will need to check if it is indeed different from -1, so your final loop would look like:

```
while (1) {
    cin >> grade;

    if (grade != -1)
        outFile << grade << endl;
    else
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

0 was entered because you have written statement
`outFile << grade<<endl;` 
before taking input in grade global variable 
so 0 is inserted in first iteration as global variables have 0 as default value 
if you don't initialize them. so write `cin>>grade;` before writing `outFile << grade<<endl;`.

Answer (score -1):

Just swap lines cin and cout. cheers